# Error building sencha app with cordova for android

Tags: android, cordova, extjs, ant

While trying to build sencha app with cordova I get teh following error:

> [ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   .sencha\app\build-impl.xml:427: The following error occurred
>   while executing this line: .sencha\app\cordova-impl.xml:170: The
>   following error occurred while executing this line:
>   jar:file://sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:584:
>   shellscript returned: 1

I'm working on windows 8.1 machine with Sencha cmd 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more Information, if you use:

> sencha -d app build native

To save CMD-Output to a File, use:

> sencha -d app build native > "C:\debug.txt"

Maybe you must install Android target 19:
Go to Android SDK Manager and install Android 4.4.2 (API19)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after adding an image to resources folder which had a german 'ß' in it.
Removing the image was not enough.
Because it was still saved in *cordova/platforms/android/assets/www/resources* and there I could not delete it. It was created automatically with every build.
To solve it,  I had to manually delete cordova-folder of my project and than than initialize cordova, to make my project a cordova-project again.

`C:\Path\To\Project> sencha cordova init`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error but at line no **660**, like "line: jar:file://sencha.jar!/com/sencha/ant/antlib.xml:660: shellscript returned: 1". 
   Then I added node.js environment variable path and got rid of this issue.